# Is it possible to switch READ_ONLY database to WAL journaling mode in sqlite3

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have opened a database connection in READ_ONLY mode. Is it possible to switch the database connection to journaling mode = WAL in runtime?

I am using below code to switch to WAL mode

```
sqlite3* ppDb;
int res = sqlite3_open_v2("test.db",&ppDb,SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY,NULL,NULL, 0, NULL);
if(SQLITE_OK==res)
{
    rc = sqlite3_exec(m_dbHandle, "PRAGMA zipvfs_journal_mode=wal;", NULL,NULL, NULL))
}
```

I am getting Disk I/O error after sqlite3_exec statement.

Can anyone please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) says:

> It is not possible to open read-only WAL databases. The opening process must have write privileges for "`-shm`" wal-index shared memory file associated with the database, if that file exists, or else write access on the directory containing the database file if the "`-shm`" file does not exist.

The same write privileges are needed if you re-open a database in WAL mode.

Comment: Hello, Is it that the media should be in RDWR mode or is it must that the file should be opened with RDWR permissions ?

Comment: `OPEN_READONLY` forbids SQLite to attempty any writing.